# how to remove vs code unnecessary characters(how to remove that "s:")?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

how to remove that "s:" in vs code [image]

Recently I have added an debugger and other java extensions may be that suggesting it and also tried some change in settings of vs code to remove this but it didn't worked.

Comment: The characters aren't actually in your file... These are called something like parameter hints. Check the settings of the Java extension.. What settings did you change already?

Comment: actually i have recently installed "extension pack for java from microsoft"  after that this started. When i uninstalled it. it vanished but i want that extension also not this ghost boxes.

Comment: Yes, it's specific to Java, but some other languages add it as well... For learning they might not be useful, but if you clone an open source repo and have no idea what code is doing, the hints help a lot (assuming parameter names make sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called "Inlay Hints", press ctrl+comma to open the settings menu, search for "Inlay Hints", and turn them off.

[image]